# Gaussian integral with offset, and other cases

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the Gaussian Integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Numerically, it seems that for any arbitrary imaginary offset, ki,
$$\int_{ki-\infty}^{ki+\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Why is this so **edit** *and how would you prove it*?  $\exp(-(x+ki)^2)=\exp(k^2) \times \exp(-x^2 - 2kix)$ gets large very quickly, yet the overall integral does not change, no matter what the value of k is.

I have another related question.  It appears that for f, an arbitrary polynomial with an even number of terms, that this might still hold, if f(x) gets arbitrarily large positive for real x as the absolute value of x gets arbitrarily large.

$$\int_{ki-\infty}^{ki+\infty} e^{-f(x)} \ dx = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-f(x)} \ dx$$

Comment: The first part is a duplicate : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/801163/140057

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a rectangle in the complex plane with vertices at $z=-R, z=R, z=R+ ik,$ and $z=-R+ik$.

Let $ f(z) = \displaystyle e^{-z^{2}}$ and integrate counterclockwise around the rectangle.

Then letting $R$ go to infinity,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} \ dx + \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{0}^{k} f(R+ it) \ i \ dt + \int_{\infty+ik}^{-\infty+ik} e^{-z^{2}} \ dz + \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{k}^{0} f(-R+it) \ i \ dt = 0 . $$

If we can show that the second and fourth integrals vanish, then we have the result.

Notice that 
$$ \begin{align} \Big| \int_{0}^{k} f(R+it) \ i \ dt \Big| & \le   \int _{0}^{k} \Big|e^{-(R+it)^{2}} \Big| \ dt  \\ &= e^{-R^{2}}\int_{0}^{k} e^{t^{2}} \ dt \end{align} $$

which vanishes as $ R \to \infty$ since $k$ is finite.

Similarly,

$$ \begin{align} \Big| \int_{0}^{k} f(-R+it) \ i \ dt \Big| &\le \int _{0}^{k} \Big| e^{-(-R+it)^{2}} \Big| dt  \\ &= e^{-R^{2}}\int_{0}^{k} e^{t^{2}} \ dt \end{align}$$ which vanishes as $R \to \infty$ for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks!  "Then letting R go to infinity" The answer says the sum of the four line integrals is zero; presumably that is true no matter what the size of the rectangle is?  I guess I was confused witht he the Cauchy integral, often used over a circle path, where $\oint_C f(a)/(z-a) dz =f(a)/2\pi i$, where as if the sum of the line integrals is zero, then yeah, its a pretty simple problem.  Sorry, easy question, I guess, but the sum of the line integrals=0 is exactly what I needed to know :)  Presumably, you get the bounty; let me chew on it for a little while

Comment: Yes because there are no singularities inside or on the rectangle.

Comment: We only care about singularities inside the rectangle, if its a finite rectangle, correct?  Probably for the infinite case as well; there are no singularities for exp(-x^2)

Comment: We apply the formula for finite $R$ and then we take the limit as $R$ goes to $\infty$. There is a good example on Wikipedia where they use the upper half of a large circle as opposed to a rectangle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28I.29 There is a related theorem that considers the singularities outside of a contour and thus takes into account the point at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Under the change of variable $x+c = y$ where we compute $\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}y$, all that changes is the range/path of integration.  (In your example, this depends on the fact that the integrand has no poles in the complex plane -- it is an [entire function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).  For an example where the integral is **not** fixed under translation of the path, see the [inverse Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform).)

$$\int_{k\mathrm{i}-\infty}^{k\mathrm{i}+\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(x+k\mathrm{i})^2} \ \mathrm{d}x 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-y^2} \ \mathrm{d}y
= \sqrt{\pi}$$

You comment on $\exp(-(k \mathrm{i})^2)$, but you neglect that $(x+k \mathrm{i})^2 = x^2 - k^2 + 2 x k \mathrm{i} $ and the $2 x k \mathrm{i} $ matters. \begin{align*}
\exp(-(k \mathrm{i})^2) &= \exp(-(x^2 - k^2 + 2 x k \mathrm{i})) \\
 &= \exp(k^2-x^2) \exp(2xk\mathrm{i}) \\
 &= \exp(k^2-x^2) (\cos(2xk) + \mathrm{i} \sin(2xk))
\end{align*} where the last line uses [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Since polynomials also have no singularities, exactly the same change of variable in the integrand will show that the value of the integral is independent of imaginary shift of the path.

Comment: Eric wrote, "Since polynomials also have no singularities, exactly the same change of variable in the integrand will show that ... the integral is independent of imaginary shift..."  I'm sorry but I don't understand this well enough to prove it. I understand the algebra, but it seems to assume a theory of Mellin transforms/Laplace transforms; I want to be able to prove the result, so I can apply to other functions. I understand the Cauchy integral on a unit circle, but not the in variance of an integral from -infinity to +infinity, although I have some guesses as to how it might be done.

Comment: The proof is the first line, using the change of variables formula in the integral.  I don't understand what more elementary proof than "a translation of a variable with infinite endpoints does not alter the integral because the immediate change of variables leaves the endpoints and integrand unchanged" is needed.

Comment: How would you show that the integral from -infinity to infinity is independent of the path?  Would you use the Cauchy integral theorem? But that is on a closed finite path.  Does it also always apply from -infinity to infinity, and if so, how would you prove it.

Comment: @SheldonL:  In the absence of singularities, there are no residues to account for.  Imagine your infinite path trying to translate laterally past a singularity -- it gets "caught" on a neighborhood of the singularity (if it is not to change its value).  You then get the translated infinite line, a segment to/from that line and the circular neighborhood of the singularity (which cancels with itself when it comes back the other way) and a circular path around the singularity.

Comment: @SheldonL:  The overwhelmingly straightforward way to see this is to realize that your infinite path is already circular.  Q.v. [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) .  So all you need to know are the residues enclosed in your great circle.

Comment: would $\sqrt{\pi}$ be the answer on the Riemann sphere as well?  Or does that matter?  What would the circle be, where the original integral was -infinity to infinity?  From the north pole to the south pole, and back around?  Gotta think some more....

Comment: @SheldonL:  Yes.  Your original path starts at the north pole, goes down a line of longitude to the south pole, then back up the opposite line of longitude to the north pole.  This is the image of the real axis.  A translation in the imaginary direction slides the south pole end along the imaginary axis holding the point at the north pole fixed, but is still just a big circle on the sphere.

Comment: hmmm, For the Riemann sphere, there is a singularity at infinity itself, for exp(-x^2)...  I guess that doesn't matter?

Comment: @SheldonL:  Only if you try to move the end of the integral at infinity ... which you can't by translation or even rotation; any path that is a line in the plane is a circle on the sphere that passes through the point at $\infty$.

Comment: This proof is very intuitive, but absolutely wrong. The rigorous proof is the one given by @RandomVariable above, using contour integration in the complex plane. The "change of variable" $y=x+k\mathbb{i}$, from real to complex, is a total nonsense.

Comment: I don't think his argument is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @AlexM.:  Please explain which hypothesis of the change of variables theorem was violated.  $|J(\dots)|$ is absolutely trivial in this case.

Comment: There is no such thing as $\int^{x+y\mathbb{i}}_{x-y\mathbb{i}}$ in mathematics, since there is no such thing as the interval $[x-y\mathbb{i}, x+y\mathbb{i}]$, even less one that has $x=\infty$. There is no room in modern integration theory for what you do, it's as simple as that. This is neither Riemann, nor Lebesgue, not even imporper integration. This is simply mathematical nonsense, it is how people used to integrate in the age of Cauchy... To me it smells like done by an engineer, not a mathematician.