# Proof of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^{2}} e^{- i 2 \pi t v} dt = e^{- \pi v^2}$ using binominal square

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I tried to proof this as a (signal engineering) homework using binomal square, but the example answer was given using differential equations. I'd like to know if my approach was possible.

I tried the following:

$$ t, v \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^{2}} e^{- i 2 \pi t v} dt $$
Expand with $e^{-\pi v^{2}} e^{\pi v^{2}}$

$$ e^{-\pi v^{2}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^{2}} e^{- i 2 \pi t v} e^{\pi v^{2}} dt $$
With $-v^{2} = (i v)^2$

$$ e^{-\pi v^{2}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi (t^{2} + 2 t (i v) +  (iv)^{2})} dt  $$

And then the binomal square

$$ e^{-\pi v^{2}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi (t + iv)^2} dt  $$

Here I got stuck. I know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2} dt = 1$, but how to proof this is also true with a complex constant?

Comment: It is enough to invoke the residue theorem. $e^{-z^2}$ is an entire function and $\left\|e^{-z^2}\right\|\to 0$ pretty fast when $\left|\text{Re}(z)\right|\to +\infty$ and $\text{Im}(z)\in[0,|v|]$.

Comment: There are several ways to derive the formula but your method doesn't work unless you invoke some results in complex analysis.

Comment: Why so much pain? $t + iv = y$ and you're done, since the differential involves only  $t$.

Comment: @VonNeumann I was told by an assistant teacher that I cannot make real number to a complex one with simple substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parity, on has $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^{2}} e^{- i 2 \pi t v} dt =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^{2}} \cos{(2 \pi v t)} \, dt.$$

Now, you can use the well-known formula $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-at^2}\cos(bt)\,dt
=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}.$$ If you don't know this formula, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362987/evaluatig-int-0-inftyeax2-cosbxdx).

Comment: Could you give example how this solves $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi (t + iv)^{2}} dt$?

Comment: But... I did. Develop the square, then consider the real part and the imaginary part. By parity, the imaginary part is $0$ and the real part is what I wrote in my post.

Comment: I might have misunderstood this, but I think this means that I should/can not use binominal square to solve this. (By opening the square and "removing" the multiplication by 1.)

Comment: Indeed. Without complex analysis, completing the square is not the good strategy.