# How can I calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(2bx)\,\mathrm{d}x$ using residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(2bx)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
How can I prove this integral equals $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-b^2}$ by using the residue theorem?

For $b>0$ and $\gamma_R$ a middle circle of radius $R$ up $x$-axis, I tried doing
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\gamma_R}e^{-z^2}e^{2ibz}\,\mathrm{d}z&=0
\end{align*}
since $f(z)=e^{-z^2}e^{2ibz}$ is continous over $\gamma_R$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1363059/42969.

Comment: Next you need to investigate whether the part on the semicircle goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.  This will tell us whether this contour is a good one to use.

Comment: After completing the square and a change of variables $z=x-ib$ you basically want to prove $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2} \, {\rm d}z = \sqrt{\pi} \, .$$ You can shift the contour as you like, since the integrand is holomorphic. But other than that what makes you think contour integration is a good approach to calculate the latter integral?