# Why is this evaluation of $\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2}\sin(ax) x^{-1} dx$ by completion of the square valid?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to derive equation 3.9526 from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2}\sin(ax) x^{-1} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{a}{2p} \right)$$
I start with 
$$\begin{align}I(a)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2}\sin(ax) x^{-1} dx\\
I'(a)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2}\cos(ax) dx = \Re \int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2 + iax} dx\end{align}$$
I complete the square:
$$I'(a)=\exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4p^2}\right)\Re \int_0^\infty dx\exp\left( -p^2 \left[ x-\frac{ia}{2p^2}\right]^2\right) $$
And then I do the following step (**the question is: Why can I do this?**)
$$I'(a)=\exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4p^2}\right)\Re \int_{0-\frac{ia}{2p^2}}^{\infty-\frac{ia}{2p^2}} dz\exp\left( -p^2 z^2\right) \overset{\text{why?}}{=} \exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4p^2}\right)\Re \int_0^\infty dz\exp\left( -p^2 z^2\right) $$
which yields $I'(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2p} \exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4p^2}\right)$ and hence $I(a)=\int_0^a dy I'(y)=\frac{\pi}{2}\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{a}{2p} \right)$. So the result is ok, but I am unsure why the equality with the question mark should hold... I am pretty sure that it is only true because we take the real part of the integral, but I cannot find a satisfactory explanation...

**Edit:** I guess I have an idea now: In general I want
$$\Re \int_0^\infty dx f(x+i\epsilon)= \int_0^\infty dx f(x)$$ which should hold if 
$$\Re f(x+i\epsilon) = f(\Re (x+ i\epsilon))=f(x)$$
And the last equality should hold for any complex function which is analytic, since I can use $\Re (z+w) = \Re(z) + \Re(w)$ and $\Re(z^n) = (\Re z)^n$ in the Taylor series. Is this argument correct?

Comment: It's actually because [the value of the Gaussian integral over a path in $\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the integral over $\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865287/gaussian-integral-with-offset-and-other-cases)

Comment: I think it must be $$\frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{2|p|}\right)$$

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for the link! Could you check my text under "Edit"? Does this hold for any analytic $f(z)$? The answer in your link uses that $f(z)$ vanishes quickly at infinity.

Comment: For $p > 0$ you get $I'(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2x^2}\cos(ax) dx =\frac12 F(ia)$, $ F(b)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p^2x^2 + bx} dx = e^{(b/(2p))^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(px-b/(2p))^2} dx$. Here you need to show $G(b)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(px-b/(2p)^2} dx$ doesn't depend on $b$, which is a consequence of its complex-analyticity : $G(b)$ is constant for $b \in \Bbb{R}$, thus it must be constant for $b \in \Bbb{C}$.